# Swashbuckle Example Data Type not showing correct markup

Tags: xml, vb.net, swashbuckle, .net-4.8, swashbuckle.examples

I am trying to get my SwashBuckle/Swagger GUI to show the correct elements based on how I set it in code. Currently the example output looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <SomesModel>
     <_Somes>
       <_SomeID>string</_SomeID>
       <_SomeName>string</_SomeName>
       <_SomeBool>true</_SomeBool>
     </_Somes>
    </SomesModel>
```

My current code structure looks like this:

WepApiConfig

```
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = True
    SwaggerConfig.Register(config)
```

Controller code

```
    <HttpPost>
    Public Function PostGeneric(some As SomesModel) As HttpResponseMessage
        Return New HttpResponseMessage(Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
    End Function
```

Root XML object

```
    <Serializable()>
    <XmlRoot(ElementName:="Somes", [Namespace]:="")>
    <XmlType("Somes")>
    Public Class SomesModel
     <XmlElement(ElementName:="Some")>
     Public Property Somes As List(Of SomeModel)
    End Class
```

Sub XML Object

```
   <Serializable()>
   <XmlType("Some")>
   Public Class SomeModel
     <XmlElement>
     Public Property SomeID As String
     <XmlElement>
     Public Property SomeName As String
     <XmlElement>
     Public Property SomeBool As Boolean
   End Class
```

I specify all the annotations that I normally do when serializing a xml.
What extra settings does SwashBuckle need to get the xml serialized correctly?

I have tried editing the xml annotations, but it seems like Swashbuckle just ignores them. Some stack overflow suggestions was to try XMLType and others suggested using XMLRoot and XmlElements. I have tried all combinations of those.

What I would expect it to look like is this as the output.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Somes>
      <_Some>
        <_SomeID>string</_SomeID>
        <_SomeName>string</_SomeName>
        <_SomeBool>true</_SomeBool>
      </_Some>
     <_Some>
       <_SomeID>string</_SomeID>
       <_SomeName>string</_SomeName>
       <_SomeBool>true</_SomeBool>
     </_Some>
    </Somes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time digging I found [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/712)

The solution is to create a class that Implements ISchemaFilter
My apply method had this structure

```
Public Sub Apply(schema As Schema, registry As SchemaRegistry, type As Type) Implements ISchemaFilter.Apply
```

You get the type.GetCustomAttributes(True) to get all the classes custom attributes and find the one you are looking for and use the xml element like this

```
Dim castedAttr = DirectCast(attr, XmlRootAttribute)
schema.xml = New Xml With
{
   .name = castedAttr.ElementName
}
```

Next you go through the type.Properties() and then go through the CustomAttributes for each property and you set the xml element like

```
schema.properties(property.Name).xml  = New Xml With
{
   .name = castedAttr.ElementName
}
```

Last you go into your SwaggerConfig class and add

```
c.SchemaFilter(Of YourNewClass)()
```